# Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://our-website.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: nginx, header, x-frame-options

We are trying to access our source website in a third-party client website using Iframe.
As per suggestions we enabled the below conf in nginx in our source server

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "allow-from http://client-website.com" always;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' http://client-website.com" always;
```

But right now the issue is ,
In firefox, while accesing it via client-website its working fine without any issue but for chrome and safari it giving the below error :

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
> "https://our-website.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Firefox:Version : 114.0.2
Chrome :Version 118.0.5993.70

Is there anything extra needed for chrome to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have allowed http://client-website.com, while request is coming from https://client-website.com, the scheme differs.

Also, it seems like ".com" is missing for X-Frame-Options, but as you implement the frame-ancestors directive it is ignored in most browsers. It will only be used by Internet Explorer and other very old browsers.

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my question for more clarity. We need to access our website in a client domain using a iframe. For that we added the above x frame options.. But this is working in firefox but not in chrome, Any additional settings needs to be added in our nginx configuration?

Comment: Have you checked that you are only having one Content-Security-Policy in your response headers? If you have multiple it has to pass all and if one of them has a stricter frame-ancestors it won't work.

Comment: Yes i checked and only one Content-Security-Policy is send in headers.. BTW this does work fine in firefox.

Comment: And you have fixed the http/https misconfiguration?

Comment: my client domain is not on https, but my site which has to be embedded in client domain is https.. Will this cause issue in chrome? if so why its working in firefox?

Comment: Then I might have misunderstood your configuration and errors. But looking at your error message again it might not be related to your frame controlling headers, but I'm not able to tell what the exact problem is or how to solve it.